# some options dont work in mapquest api

Tags: api, geocode, mapquest

I am working with the mapquest open geocoding api and some of the options don't work when POST ing requests to the api.

For example, this HTTP GET request adheres to the ignoreLatLngInput, thumbMaps and maxResults options

```
http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?inFormat=kvp&outFormat=json&ignoreLatLngInput=true&thumbMaps=false&maxResults=3&location=Boston,+MA
```

but when the same values are submitted via a HTTP POST they are ignored and some even cause the request to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following.

```
$.getJSON(
    "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon+"",
     function(data) {
         var loc = data.display_name;   
});
```